# Excel Cannot find Data that is within Spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm running into a very unique issue that I have never had before. I'm unsure what is causing it (or how to reproduce it to share here). I've found multiple examples of this happening within my data and I'm sure there are plenty more than what I've found, but I will speak about one specific instance below.

I have a data set that includes a list of email addresses. I know an email,  janedoe@aol.com, appears in my dataset three times. But, when I go to my email column and scroll through the filter, her email does not appear. When I type in the search bar (within the filter), it tells me no cases exist. 
But, when I use CTRL+F, the document can find her email address all three times. So I know it is there.

But...this problem is actually impacting my data. When I create pivot tables, people are being left out of the counts. And it's the people who arent being 'found' by Excel. (But they can all be found using CTRL+F).

Has anyone ever run into anything like this or have any troubleshooting tips?

Comment: Is all of your data within the table?  Try resizing the table to see where if it contains all your expected data.

Comment: It's not formatted as a table, just raw data in Excel (coming from an SPSS export)

Comment: Extra spaces somewhere?

Comment: How many unique rows of emails do you have in your data?  I've seen cases where the autofilter dropdown will display a message that not all items could be displayed but not sure what the trigger for that is.

Comment: If you have a gap in your data (an empty row) then the filter option, sometimes, stops there. For example, if your data is in rows 2 to 300 but row 15 is blank then your filter option may stop at row 14. This means it will not find data in rows 16 to 300. You can get around this by highlighting all rows (in this case row 1 to 300) and all columns and then adding a filter. Not sure if this is the solution, but worth a try.

Comment: There are 179,379 rows total. I've also seen that message that not all values are displayed, but I dont see it here (also, I dont remember if I searched within the filter, if it would still come up or not?) Also, if this was the case, would it affect the pivot table the way it is?

Comment: There are no blank rows/extra spaces. It's just a raw data export from SPSS so there shouldnt be any missing values anywhere (but also I double checked for this within the file and theres nothing)

Comment: based on these statements : "CTRL+F, the document can find her email address all three times. ".. & " I type in the search bar (within the filter), it tells me no cases exist." .. I'm pretty confident that the data is not located at the intended column. (which explains why it's not filtered/included @ pivot data). .. just my imho. || suggested workaround : need to check the affected column and manually correcting it. I had experienced some text-to table/ excel conversion that messed up.. Thus, proposing this statement. ( :